# Guardar datos tipo date de forma correcta en la base de datos MySql

Tags: php, html, excel, mvc

Buenos días estoy almacenando en mi base de datos MySql datos desde un excel pero lo que ocurre es que las fechas no se están guardando de forma correcta. este es el formato que utilizo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo cual desde la vista de mi pagina lo paso al controlador para enviar los datos a la base de datos, con el siguiente código:

```
public function subirArchivo(){


        if (!empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) {


            $pathinfo = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);


            if (($pathinfo['extension'] == 'xlsx' || $pathinfo['extension'] == 'xls') 
            && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0 ) {

                // Nombre Temporal del Archivo
                $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 

                //Lee el Archivo usando ReaderFactory
                $reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX);

                //Esta linea mantiene el formato de nuestras horas y fechas
                //Sin esta linea Spout convierte la hora y fecha a su propio formato
                //predefinido como DataTime

                $reader->setShouldFormatDates(true);

                // Abrimos el archivo
                $reader->open($inputFileName);
                $count = 1;

                //Numero de Hojas en el Archivo
                foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
                    $logs = array(
                        'tipocarga' => 'Causas',
                        'usuariocarga'  => $_SESSION['usuarios'],
                        'ultimacarga'  => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                    );

                    $this->db->replace('cargas_sistema', $logs);                    
                    // Numero de filas en el documento EXCEL

                    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

                        // Lee los Datos despues del encabezado
                        // El encabezado se encuentra en la primera fila
                        if($count > 1) {

                            $data = array(

                                //rut_usu, fecha_ini, y fecha_ter son imputs del formulario
                                //no se encuentran en el archivo EXCEL
                                //los estoy capturando por POST
                                'rit' => $row[0],
                                'tipo_termino' => $row[1],
                                'fecha_termino' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[2])),
                                'fecha_certificado' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[3]))
                                //            'fecha_ter' => $this->input->post('fecha_ter') // dato pasado por post

                            ); 
                            $this->db->insert('causas_informe',$data);                            
                        } 
                        $count++;                      
                    } 

                }                  
                // cerramos el archivo EXCEL

                $reader->close();


            } else {

                echo "Seleccione un tipo de Archivo Valido";
            }

        } else {

            echo "Seleccione un Archivo EXCEL";

        }


    }
```

pero las fechas en la base de datos quedan de la siguiente forma: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes añadir código en vez de imágenes, por favor.

Comment: @VickMuñoz esta todo el código del controlador que mas necesitan.

Comment: no puedo ver las imágenes y no se como tengas el campo de fecha en tu base de datos, por eso la solicitud.

Comment: @NicolasRudisky al utilizar `strtotime()` debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente: Las fechas en los formatos m/d/y o d-m-y no son ambiguas al observar el separador entre los distintos componentes: **si el separador es una barra (/), se asume el formato norteamericano m/d/y;** mientras que si el separador es un guion (-) o un punto (.), se asume el formato europeo d-m-y. Si, sin embargo, el año se proporciona en un formato de dos dígitos y el separador es un guion (-, la cadena de la fecha se analiza como y-m-d.

Answer (score 0):

Convierte las fechas a un formato soportado por strtotime:
[Formatos de fecha aceptados por strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php)

```
function parseDate($date){
    $dateSplitted = explode('/', $date);
    return strtotime($dateSplitted[2] . '-' . $dateSplitted[1] . '-' . $dateSplitted[0]);
}
$seconds = parseDate($row[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

debes cambiar esta linea:

```
'fecha_termino' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[2]))
```

primero debemos crear una funcion:

```
function date_f($date){
  list($y,$m,$d) = explode("/",$date);
  return sprintf("%s-%s-%s",$y,$m,$d);
}
```

ahora le pasamos la fecha:

```
'fecha_termino' => date_f($row[2]);
```